# Conditional query depending on 2 checkbox

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a query that depends on several input form values, and at some point I am working on three values.  The first value queried has to be always 0, so I have this:

```
.. AND value_1 = 0
```

What I want to be able to do cleanly is the following:

If checkbox_2 is checked:

```
... AND (value_1 = 0 OR value_2 = 0)
```

If checkbox_3 is checked

```
... AND (value_1 = 0 OR value_3 = 0)
```

If checkbox_2 and checkbox_3 are checked

```
... AND (value_1 = 0 OR value_2 = 0 OR value_3 = 0)
```

I am creating the SQL query in a string, and I am wondering what would be a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to create an array filled with the options used in your SQL query and either `implode` the string together.

```
<?php

$options = array();
$options[] = 'value_1';
$options[] = 'value_2';

// add our condition to each column
array_walk($options, function(&$v) {
    $v = sprintf('%s = 0', $v);
});

// implode into SQL
$sql = sprintf('... AND (%s)', implode(' OR ', $options));
```

Just make sure you hook up your check-boxes to the `$options` array.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to that checkbox_1 is always checked plus checkbox_2 or checkbox_3? That would look like this

```
... AND value_1 = 0 AND (value_2 = 0 OR value_3 = 0)
```

Comment: No, I am not asking for that.

Comment: Ok, my bad then. Maybe you can rephrase your question then, for me it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.